# Spring Boot JWT Cors Not Working with Angular 8

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

I have my backend services in Spring Boot, and the UI in Angular 8.
I have JWT enabled so that all api calls need to be done by passing **Authorizarion** Header with the **JWT Token as the value**

I set up the CORS like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServicesApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
        
    }
}
```

After this I am able access the login API which is

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

But I am not able to access any of the Protected routes. I get the following error when calling the backend API Service.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/data' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I had setup WebSecurity like this for my JWT. Is this somehow affecting the case?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your, `WebSecurityConfig#configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)`

update as following

```java
httpSecurity
    .cors()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

    //here you add all origins possible
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost", "http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:4200"));

    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "PUT", "POST","OPTIONS", "DELETE"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization","content-type"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

You can add the annotation @CrossOrigin in each @RestController class, in this case i've wrote in the most generic way possible:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestControler
public class YourController {

...

}
```

Comment: you are just creating a bean, where are you using it?